# Passing String from dialog fragment back to previews fragment

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-alertdialog

in my dialog fragment i created

```
    public static interface OnCompleteListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(String name);
}

private OnCompleteListener mListener;
```

in the fragment where i want to receive the string there is:

```
    @Override
public void onComplete(String name) {

}
```

here is the question, what do i write here in order to send the string back to fragment:

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           String name = rename_dialog_edit.getText().toString();
       }
```

how do i send string name back to previews fragment, so that i can use it from onComplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       String name = rename_dialog_edit.getText().toString();
       ((OnCompleteListener)getActivity).onComplete(name);
}
```

Comment: i tried `mListener.onComplete(name);` , it should be same, but i also tried your suggestion, and my app crashes when the dialog needs to be created. here is the logCat in case you could help: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65257571/log2.txt

Comment: That's because `getActivity()` will never, under any circumstance, return a fragment... Two options: implement the callback in both your activity and fragment and let the activity pass on the result to the relevant fragment. Alternatively, tag your fragments and use the fragment manager to look them up, after which you can call the callback.